# Swing modal dialog go back wrongly

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, jdialog

Summary: create mulitiple modal dialog, when to close one hidden modal dialog, modal dialogs on the closed modal dialog can go back of the low level modal dialog if you click the low level modal dialog.

way to reproduce the problem , run application -> click "Button A" -> click "Button B" -> click "Button C", then Dialog C can go back of Dialog A if you click dialog a.

please help, thanks!!

```
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;

public class ModalDialogProblem {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JDialog a = new JDialog();
        a.setTitle("Dialog A");
        a.setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        a.setLayout(null);
        a.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 300);

        JButton bA = new JButton("Button A");
        bA.setBounds(20, 20, 180, 40);
        bA.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                final JDialog b = new JDialog();
                b.setTitle("Dialog B");
                b.setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                b.setLayout(null);
                b.setBounds(40, 40, 400, 300);

                JButton bB = new JButton("Button B");
                bB.setBounds(20, 20, 180, 40);
                bB.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                        JDialog c = new JDialog();
                        c.setTitle("Dialog C");
                        c.setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                        c.setLayout(null);

                        c.setBounds(80, 80, 400, 300);
                        JButton bC = new JButton("Button C");
                        bC.setBounds(20, 20, 180, 40);
                        bC.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                                b.dispose();
                            }
                        });
                        c.add(bC);
                        c.setVisible(true);
                    }
                });
                b.add(bB);
                b.setVisible(true);
                }
                });
                a.add(bA);
                a.setVisible(true);
        }
}
```

Comment: Why are there so many levels of owned dialogs?  I came up with a variant where activating the button in C caused both B & C dialogs to disappear.  Would that work for this (peculiar) use-case instead?

Comment: we need to keep Dialog C exist when to close Dialog B

Comment: as you kown, our warning dialog is modal dialog, and there can popup lots of warning dialog at the same time. so there will be many levels of owned dialogs

Comment: for example, there is warning dialog A, then warning dialog B popup, and it has a close button, press and hold the close button on Dialog B, at this time another warning dialog C pop up, then dialog B is closed automaticaly, if you click Dialog A, warning C can go back to Dialog A

Comment: In the current UI design trend even 1 dialog is less than ideal. If you have so many dialogs on the screen, this is a clear sign of a not well thought through UI design. Unfortunately, I can't help you improve it without knowing what your actual goal is, but I doubt that multiple dialogs is part of your requirements.

Answer (score -1):

In order for dialogs to function correctly you have to provide owner frame or owner dialog during dialog construction. It ensures proper visualization and fixes many glitches described. Try the following:

```
JDialog c = new JDialog(previouslyOpenedDialog);
```

Comment: *"and fixes many glitches described"*  No it doesn't.  I already tried it.

Comment: Unfortunately the dialog requires a Frame or Dialog parent, which in the context of the problem, is not available. The dialog is being shown by a keyboard event or a event triggered by background thread.